# Get order information such as inventory id, customer id and location id in a sales order during Business Logic Customization

Tags: acumatica

As I mentioned in my previous question( [How to customize the sales order process to trigger an automatic "adding contract" process when sales order is successfully completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31542707/how-to-customize-the-sales-order-process-to-trigger-an-automatic-adding-contrac)), I need to automatically add a contract for each of some particular products that are in a sales order after this sales order is added.

I have learned adding contract part in previous questions,thanks to @Gabriel's response, and now I need to know how to get those order information such as inventory id in order items, customer id and location id in a sales order business logic (screen SO301000). Would anybody please kindly provide me some sample code?

Thanks.

---

Now I seem to be able to get customer id and location id from code:

```
SOOrder SalesOrder = (SOOrder)Base.Caches[typeof(SOOrder)].Current; 
int customer_id = SalesOrder.CustomerID; 
int Location ID = SalesOrder.CustomerLocationID;
....
```

but I still need to find out how to iterate through product list (SOLine item) in the order...the code I found as below (it was an example for implementing a SO release operation) in T200 training PDF seems too old and not helpful to me:

```
public static void ReleaseOrder(SalesOrder order)
{
  SalesOrderEntry graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<SalesOrderEntry>();
  graph.Orders.Current = order;
  foreach (OrderLine line in graph.OrderDetails.Select())
  {
    ProductQty productQty = new ProductQty();
    productQty.ProductID = line.ProductID;
    productQty.AvailQty = -line.OrderQty;
    graph.Stock.Insert(productQty);
   }
    order.ShippedDate = graph.Accessinfo.BusinessDate;
    order.Status = OrderStatus.Completed;
    graph.Orders.Update(order);
    graph.Persist();
}
```

Comment: Have you completed the various Acumatica developer trainings? This is a very broad question that is covered in these trainings.

Comment: @Gabriel, sorry I just downloaded whatever I could get from Acumatica Open University site and read those PDFs, although the T300 training material over there seems out-of-date. Is there a formal developer training(either online or classroom)?

Comment: I just edited my question.

Comment: We have a complete certification process for developers - you need to complete T100 and T200...

Comment: @Gabriel, Thanks for your response - I have read through all T100, T200 and T300, although I admit I didn't try each of examples, but the PDF document seems out-of-date as some of the menus and methods don't seem to work. By the way, I was just editing my post while you added your comment - could you please take a look at my edits? Thanks.

Comment: @Gladiator, Menus have indeed changed in V5 but the bases of customization stay the same. If you are comfortable with the exercises in V4 you will be in V5 too.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you have to loop through the lines while you override persist in your extension

```
 foreach (SOLine line in this.Base.Transactions.Select())
 {
 }
```

What you are doing here is you are looping through the valid records in the cache by executing select method. For this you have to find the view definition (Transactions) related to the DAC(SOLine) from the Base BLC definitions.

Comment: I'd like to add to the answer that even though @Gladiator 's line to get the current element works, it's overly complicated: `SOOrder SalesOrder = (SOOrder)Base.Caches[typeof(SOOrder)].Current;` could be replace with  `SOOrder salesOrder = Base.Transactions.Current;`

Comment: Please Note: if it is SOOrder, the view defnition associated will be 'Document'  not 'Transactions' i think. so, Base.Document.Current

Comment: You're right @Hybridzz. Transactions are for SOLines. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it and the below is the code what I have and it's working for me so far - you can see I use "SOLine_RowPersisted" instead of customizing "Persist()" as I did before.

```
protected virtual void SOLine_RowPersisted(PXCache sender,PXRowPersistedEventArgs e)
{           
    if (e.TranStatus == PXTranStatus.Completed)
    {
        if ((e.Operation & PXDBOperation.Command) == PXDBOperation.Insert)
        {
           SOOrder SalesOrder = (SOOrder)Base.Caches[typeof(SOOrder)].Current;

           SOLine line = (SOLine)e.Row;                

           // Lookup inventory
           InventoryItem template = PXSelect<InventoryItem,
                                    Where<InventoryItem.inventoryID, Equal<Required<InventoryItem.inventoryID>>>>
                          .Select(Base, line.InventoryID);
           if (template.InventoryCD == null)
           {
             throw new PXException("Inventory CD can not be blank.");
           }

           if (template.InventoryCD.StartsWith("AAABBB"))
           {
               ContractMaint contractMaint = PXGraph.CreateInstance<ContractMaint>();
               CTBillEngine engine = PXGraph.CreateInstance<CTBillEngine>();
               DateTime StartDate = DateTime.Now;

               ........
               string contractCD = ......
               Contract contract = SetupActivateContract(contractMaint, contractCD, StartDate , line.CustomerID, SalesOrder.CustomerLocationID, engine);
            }           
       } else if ((e.Operation & PXDBOperation.Command) == PXDBOperation.Delete)
       {
         .....
       } else if ((e.Operation & PXDBOperation.Command) == PXDBOperation.Update)
       {
         ....
        }

     }   
}
```

Comment: this event will trigger for each line in the sales order, also one more thing to note is that it will trigger while deleting too. As Gabriel pointed out this is a very base thing to know, you have to go through the development tutorials.

Comment: @Hybridzz, thanks for reminding - yes, you are right about the delete and update events, which I have just added into my code as above to demonstrate what I was planning to do. The initial code was just a proof-of-concept and eventually I would have to handle all of the "insert","update" and "delete" events.